# Consistent \contentsline between listings

Tags: table-of-contents, memoir

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\listequationname{List of Equations}
\newlistof{listofequations}{equ}{\listequationname}
\newcommand{\myequation}[1]{%
    \addcontentsline{equ}{equation}{%
        \protect\numberline{\theequation} #1%
    }%
}


\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \bgroup
      \chapterstyle{article}
      \tableofcontents
      \listoffigures
      \listoftables
      \listofequations
    \egroup

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{A section}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \caption{some figure caption}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{table}[htbp]
            \caption{some table caption}
        \end{table}
        \begin{gather}
            y = mx + b \label{eqn:linear}
        \end{gather}\myequation{Linear Equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I ensure the entries in the new listing (list of equations) are exactly the same as for the list of figures, and the list of tables?

Here is what the following above looks like, see the difference in indentations etc, lack of dots etc...

[image: Example]

I am working on my thesis, and this is being manifested like the following, where the top record is the last item in the list of figures, which you can compare to the first record in the list of equations immediately below.

[image: thesis]

Basically, I want the list of figures, list of tables, and any custom lists created by `\newlistof{...}` to look completely identical.

I have looked at the aux files, and the items are the same in terms of the macro being called:

```
\contentsline {table}{\numberline {B.5}{\ignorespaces Al SpeciesDiffision Coefficients}}{110}{table.caption.69}

\contentsline {equation}{\numberline {1.1}{\ignorespaces Expression for Critical Cooing Rate, From Heat Capacity and Sample Size}}{10}{equation.1.1.1}
```

With the only difference (apart from actual content, which is text) being the first argument, so how can I ensure:

```
\contentsline{figure}{...}
\contentsline{table}{...}
\contentsline{equation}{...}
\contentsline{<ANY OTHER CUSTOM LISTING>}{...}
```

All get formatted in the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had it almost right.

- The command

  ```
  \newlistentry[chapter]{equation}{equ}{0}
  ```

  specifies that the equation entries are to be entries on level 0 (e.g. no indentation).
- In the list of figures and tables some extra space is inserted as separator between different chapters. If you want the same for the list of equations, add the lines

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \g@addto@macro\insertchapterspace{\addtocontents{equ}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
  \makeatother
  ```
- If you want to have an `\addcontentsline` command identical to the one used in `\caption` commands, use

  ```
  \newcommand{\myequation}[1]%
    {\addcontentsline
      {equ}%
      {equation}%
      {\protect\numberline{\theequation}{\ignorespaces #1}}%
    }
  ```

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand\listequationname{List of Equations}
\newlistof{listofequations}{equ}{\listequationname}
\newlistentry[chapter]{equation}{equ}{0}
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\insertchapterspace{\addtocontents{equ}{\protect\addvspace{10pt}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\myequation}[1]%
  {\addcontentsline
    {equ}%
    {equation}%
    {\protect\numberline{\theequation}{\ignorespaces #1}}%
  }

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \bgroup
      \chapterstyle{article}
      \tableofcontents
      \listoffigures
      \listoftables
      \listofequations
    \egroup

    \mainmatter
    \chapter{A chapter}
    \section{A section}
        \begin{figure}[htbp]
            \caption{some figure caption}
        \end{figure}
        \begin{table}[htbp]
            \caption{some table caption}
        \end{table}
        \begin{gather}
            y = mx + b \label{eqn:linear}
        \end{gather}\myequation{Linear Equation}
\end{document}
```